# Pass column value from Select query to another query for insertion in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I was thinking of accomplishing the following as a PHP multi_query. But I'm trying to figure out how to pass the column value from the select query to the insert and update queries.

```
$query = "SELECT tbl_links.link, link_id
                    FROM tbl_links
                    INNER JOIN tbl_items ON tbl_links.item_id = tbl_items.item_id
                    WHERE tbl_items.item_name like '".$items_name[$counter]."'
                                    AND NOT EXISTS (
                                            select link_id 
                                            from tbl_clickedlinks 
                                            where tbl_clickedlinks.link_id = tbl_links.link_id
                                            AND tbl_clickedlinks.cust_id = '$items_custID[$counter]'
                                            )
                    limit 0, 1;" ;
            $query .= "INSERT INTO tbl_claimedlinks (cust_id, link_id, claim_time) VALUES ('$items_custID', $row['link_id'], NOW()) ;";
            $query .= "UPDATE tbl_links SET click_count = click_count+1 where link_id = '$linkID' ;";*/
```

Problem is, I'm not sure how to pass the link_id value to the other queries. So I'm thinking I might have to rearrange the queries into one, but again, I'm just not sure how to pull that off.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute select query 1st then use its output to execute 2nd & 3rd query.

```
$query = "SELECT tbl_links.link, link_id
                    FROM tbl_links
                    INNER JOIN tbl_items ON tbl_links.item_id = tbl_items.item_id
                    WHERE tbl_items.item_name like '".$items_name[$counter]."'
                                    AND NOT EXISTS (
                                            select link_id 
                                            from tbl_clickedlinks 
                                            where tbl_clickedlinks.link_id = tbl_links.link_id
                                            AND tbl_clickedlinks.cust_id = '$items_custID[$counter]'
                                            )
                    limit 0, 1;" ;

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $query2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_claimedlinks (cust_id, link_id, claim_time) VALUES ('$items_custID', $row['link_id'], NOW()) ;";
  $query3 = "UPDATE tbl_links SET click_count = click_count+1 where link_id = '$linkID' ;";*/

  mysql_query($query2);
  mysql_query($query3);
}
```